# ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function with max and sum function Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I try this query

```
 select a2.Email_account, o2.Numero_ordine, totale_ordine2.totale as totale_ordine, totale_ordine1.totale as totale_riferimento
from
    account a1, account a2, ordine o1, ordine o2,
    (
        select o.Numero_ordine as ordine,  SUM(b.Prezzo * b.Quantita) as totale
        from biglietto b, ordine o
        where
            b.Numero_ordine = o.Numero_ordine
        group by b.Numero_ordine
    ) totale_ordine1,
    (
        select o.Numero_ordine as ordine,  SUM(b.Prezzo * b.Quantita) as totale from biglietto b, ordine o
        where
            b.Numero_ordine = o.Numero_ordine
        group by b.Numero_ordine
    ) totale_ordine2
where 
    a1.Email_account ='Vita.Devlen@gmail.com'
    and a1.Email_account = o1.Email_account
    and o2.Email_account = a2.Email_account
    and o1.Numero_ordine = totale_ordine1.ordine
    and o2.Numero_ordine = totale_ordine2.ordine
    and totale_ordine2.totale > max(totale_ordine1.totale);
```

but i have the error ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function.
I understand the problem is the sum and max function but i don't know how to resolve

Comment: In the last line `totale_ordine2.totale > max(totale_ordine1.totale)`. To compute a `MAX()` you need a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @TheImpaler the sub queries already have group by and the main query doesn't need group by and i don't know which column need it

Comment: Those `GROUP BY` are only in scope of the subqueries. If you want the value `max(totale_ordine1.totale)` available in the main query maybe you could compute it in one of the subqueries and name it using `AS`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.